# CUDA 5.0 Header Files

Tags: c++, cuda

I am struggling with someone's terribly written project and I'm trying to get it compiled ASAP... (best approach would be to do this correctly but time is an issue) ... anyways, they seem to have written this with an older API, where `#include <cuda.h>` gave you access to the api functions.

**It seems the API functions have been moved to other headers and `#include <cuda.h>` is no longer enough.** What should I do:

1. Include cuda_runtime_api.h and other header files
2. Compile this cpp (no kernel function calls) with nvcc?

TIA

Comment: Either method should work.  With CUDA 5.0, and compiling with g++ or cl.exe (i.e. not nvcc) normally including `cuda_runtime.h` should be enough to get you the entire runtime functionality described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html).  You might need other header files beyond that if you are using CUBLAS, CUFFT, etc. also, but I don't think simply including `cuda.h` would have picked those up in previous versions of CUDA.  Using the second method, nvcc will hand host-only code off to the host c++ compiler anyway (e.g. g++)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Robert. So I am correct in assuming the new headers are the new canonical approach to CUDA headers (before I'm pretty sure it was just `cuda.h`

Comment: You should not need to explicitly include `cuda.h` if you are only using the cuda runtime API to access CUDA functionality.  If you are using the driver API, things are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

// includes CUDA Runtime
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

// maybe you need also helpers
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include <helper_functions.h> // helper utility functions
```

you need to add

> /usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin/nvcc

as C++ `Compiler -> Tool` also. works with g++ 4.4

in your `.cu` file you need then `#include <curand_kernel.h>` if you are using [CURAND library](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/index.html)

as Robert Crovella said:

> You should not need to explicitly include cuda.h if you are only using
>   the cuda runtime API to access CUDA functionality. If you are using
>   the driver API, things are different.

Comment: @Constatntin I don't need to include <cuda.h>

Comment: You shouldn't need to include `curand_kernel.h` unless you are using functionality from the [CURAND library](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/index.html).